# Не получается запустить пробное приложение, ошибка компиляции

Tags: java, android, json

Прошу помочь новичку!

Решил попробовать Android Studio и по уроку с youtube (см.картинку) сделал все 1 в 1, но у меня ничего не работает.

В чем проблема?

```java
package com.example.dimastik86.next_try;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String str = "123456768";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

        String srtTest = gson.toJson(str);
        String srtTest1 = gson.toJson(new Person("1212",5));

        System.out.println("to Json");
        System.out.println("strTest:\n"+strTest);
        System.out.println("strTest1:\n"+strTest1);

        String test = gson.fromJson(srtTest, String.class);
        Person person =  gson.fromJson(srtTest1, String.class);

        System.out.println("from Json");
        System.out.println("test:\n"+test);
        System.out.println("person:\nname: "+ person.getName()+"\nage: "+ person.getAge());
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dimastik86.next_try;

    public class Person {

        private String name;
        private int age;

        public Person(String name, int age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        public void setAge(int age) {
            this.age = age;
        }
    }
```

Выходит ошибка:

```
error: cannot find symbol System.out.println("strTest:\n"+strTest); symbol: variable strTest location: class MainActivity error: cannot find symbol System.out.println("strTest1:\n"+strTest1); symbol: variable strTest1 location: class MainActivity rror: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Person person = gson.fromJson(srtTest1, String.class);
```

[image: ПРИМЕР]

Comment: Давайте-ка попонятнее. В чем выражается "не работает"? Как должно работать?

Comment: :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: @МитяТо-Да-Се может вам начать с обычной джавы, не с андроидной? Там намного легче разобраться новичку.

Comment: @МитяТо-Да-Се как вы запускаете код? С помощью кнопки запуска в меню IDE? Странную ошибку вы приводите, точнее странно, что у вас нет описания ошибки.

Comment: я как бы понимаю что к чему, полагаю что это студия выделывается, или вы хотите сказать, что я ошибку сделал? к тому же текст слово в слово переписан...

Comment: пишет Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details., ругается : error: cannot find symbol System.out.println("strTest:\n"+strTest);
                                        
  symbol:   variable strTest
  location: class MainActivity
 error: cannot find symbol System.out.println("strTest1:\n"+strTest1);
                                         
  symbol:   variable strTest1
  location: class MainActivity
rror: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Person person =  gson.fromJson(srtTest1, String.class); запускаю кнопкой из меню

Comment: в инете пишут, что можно обновить buildToolsVersion до «23.0.1» или что это из-за возможного конфликта разных версий джавы на пк, но где и как обновить buildToolsVersion я не разобрался, а джаву в настройках насильно прописал

Comment: @МитяТо-Да-Се странно, такое ощущение, что у вас не уст. жава

Comment: снес всю джаву с пк, вместе с ней - студию тоже... почитил клинером, установил по новой - НИЧЕГО (( любая помощь будет принята с удовольствием!

Comment: "полагаю что это студия выделывается" -- это обычная мысль начинающих программистов :) "Я не вижу тут никакой ошибки, значит это компилятор неправильно работает!!!". А в это время у вас компилятор выдает совершенно ясное сообщение: `incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Person: person = gson.fromJson(srtTest1, String.class);`

Comment: "снес всю джаву с пк, вместе с ней - студию тоже... почитил клинером, установил по новой - НИЧЕГО " -- надо было еще компьютер поменять и ОС переставить. Это круто, но, по моему опыту, это редко помогает найти ошибку в своем коде ;)

Comment: комп было бы не плохо тоже почистить )) но это в след раз... и как поменять тип? подскажи пожалуйста, где и что поправить, чтобы рабочий пример получился! спасибо!

Comment: `Person person =  gson.fromJson(srtTest1, Person.class);` - вторым параметром нужно передавать тип, который хотим получить.